# Python KafkaProducer Proceeding to force close the producer since pending requests could not be completed within timeout

Tags: kafka-producer-api

Reporting an issue here.  The producer threw the errors below.  Waited an hour or so and the error went away. But while I had the error I could list topics using using the Kafka tool while the Kafka Python API would not work:

```
kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --from-beginning --topic tweets
```

Here is the error from the python program:

> INFO:kafka.producer.kafka:Proceeding to force close the producer since
>   pending requests could not be completed within timeout 0.

Using

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')
```

Answer (score 2):

Its very likely that your producer kernel is shutting down as soon as it sends the message; even before the consumer is able to consume and display the message. Can you try adding sleep(seconds) to your producer script ad try. Worked for me!